# RESTORE class .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server

Will the `SQLRESTORE` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.sqlrestore%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in .NET automatically restore a database using the `WITH REPLACE` option if it sees the noted database is already attached? The technet article is unclear, and `ReplaceDatabase` [seems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.replacedatabase%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to default to replacing the database if one is attached.

Comment: You could try it and see - use it on a benign database, and run a trace on the DB server to see what executes.

Comment: It's not clear to me, either. I'll second @JonEgerton that you should set up a test to try it and find out, with the addition that once you get your answer, make sure to use the "Community Additions" feature on the msdn documentation page to add the information there.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that and update this question.

Comment: I added the information as an answer instead, and submitted a clarification to the Technet article. Hopefully it will help clear it up for anyone else who might see that as confusing.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `SQLRESTORE` will not use `WITH REPLACE` and will fail with an unhandled exception at runtime.

To mimic the functionality of `WITH REPLACE`, which allows a database to be restored overtop of an existing database, you will need to call the `ReplaceDatabase` method and set it to true for the database to be restored.

For example:

```
Sub RestoreHM()
    Dim srv As Server = New Server("SQLServer02")
    Dim rs As Restore = New Restore()
    Console.WriteLine(srv.Information.Version)
    rs.Devices.AddDevice("G:\backup.bak", DeviceType.File)
    rs.NoRecovery = True
    rs.ReplaceDatabase = True
    rs.Database = "Database"
    rs.SqlRestore(srv)
    Console.WriteLine("Database has been restored.")
End Sub
```